# bash: how to search certain texts and delete from a file?

Tags: shell, sed

I've got a text file like this:

```
20173041 user name build/release/src/file1.cpp
20173041 John build/debug/master/file1.cpp
20173041 J.F.K build/test/testsrc/file1.cpp
20173041 uk us build/profile/branch/file1.cpp
```

I wish to eliminate all "build/xxxx/" from each line and get a file like this:

```
20173041 user name src/file1.cpp
20173041 John master/file1.cpp
20173041 J.F.K testsrc/file1.cpp
20173041 uk us branch/file1.cpp
```

The eliminated text always start with "build". How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `GNU sed` with a `regEx` pattern for searching the pattern. Notice the change in field separator to `|` to avoid escaping while using the `/` within the search pattern.

```
sed -r 's|build/[[:alnum:]]+/||g' file2
20173041 user name src/file1.cpp
20173041 John master/file1.cpp
20173041 J.F.K testsrc/file1.cpp
20173041 uk us branch/file1.cpp
```

Add a `-i.bak`

```
sed -i.bak -r 's|build/[[:alnum:]]+/||g' file2
```

Comment: This is the best answer that matches all possible cases.

Comment: @Troskyvs :Happy to be of help!

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it with awk using multiple delimiters like this:

```
$ echo "20173041 user name build/release/src/file1.cpp" |awk -F"[ /]" '{print $1,$2,$3,$6"/"$7}'
20173041 user name src/file1.cpp
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F/ '{sub(/ build/,"")}{print $1,$(NF-1)"/"$NF}' file

20173041 user name src/file1.cpp
20173041 John master/file1.cpp
20173041 J.F.K testsrc/file1.cpp
20173041 uk us branch/file1.cpp
```